# photon rpc is not calling correctly(Photon RPC with character generating)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc, multiplayer, photon

I'm trying to generate character with script.
I have '`playerObj`' and '`model`' pref under resource folder. `playerObj` has all the script related controlling, and `photonView`, `Camera`, etc. and model has `animation`, `skin renderer`, and `photonView`.

What am I trying to do is, instantiating `playerObj` and instantiating model object together. and with model obj, I want to add some skin mesh so it has character's model (I did this so player is able to change model's outfit) and then parenting `playerObj` with model.

Problem is it did instantiating own character correctly, but the instantiating other character is wrong.
it will instantiating both `playerObj` and `model Obj`. but it doesn't rendering skin mesh and doesn't parenting those two...
I don't know what i did wrong or missing something...

as you see down of the script i'm using three different script to generate character.

Thank you.

***PlayerInit.cs***

```
public IEnumerator CreateCharacter()
{
    var co = CurrentCharacter.GetByGUI(dbid);
    co.InitModel(character, dbid);

    m_loaded = true;
    m_loading = false;
}
```

***CharacterGenerator.cs***

```
public GameObject Generate(PhotonView pv)
{
    int id1 = PhotonNetwork.AllocateViewID();
    GameObject root = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Model", new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), new Quaternion (0, 0, 0, 0),0);
    root.name = "body";
    Generate (pv, root);
    return root;
}
public GameObject Generate(PhotonView pv, GameObject root)
{
    int id1 = PhotonNetwork.AllocateViewID();
    putSkin (root);
    pv.RPC("putSkin", PhotonTargets.Others, root, id1, PhotonNetwork.player);
    return root;
}
// Creates a character based on the currentConfiguration recycling a
// character base, this way the position and animation of the character
// are not changed.
[RPC]
public void putSkin(GameObject root){
    float startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

    // The SkinnedMeshRenderers that will make up a character will be
    // combined into one SkinnedMeshRenderers using multiple materials.
    // This will speed up rendering the resulting character.
    List<CombineInstance> combineInstances = new List<CombineInstance>();
    List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();
    List<Transform> bones = new List<Transform>();
    Transform[] transforms = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

    foreach (CharacterElement element in currentConfiguration.Values)
    {
        SkinnedMeshRenderer smr = element.GetSkinnedMeshRenderer();
        materials.AddRange(smr.materials);
        for (int sub = 0; sub < smr.sharedMesh.subMeshCount; sub++)
        {
            CombineInstance ci = new CombineInstance();
            ci.mesh = smr.sharedMesh;
            ci.subMeshIndex = sub;
            combineInstances.Add(ci);
        }

        // As the SkinnedMeshRenders are stored in assetbundles that do not
        // contain their bones (those are stored in the characterbase assetbundles)
        // we need to collect references to the bones we are using
        foreach (string bone in element.GetBoneNames())
        {
            foreach (Transform transform in transforms)
            {
                if (transform.name != bone) continue;
                bones.Add(transform);
                break;
            }
        }

        Object.Destroy(smr.gameObject);
    }

    // Obtain and configure the SkinnedMeshRenderer attached to
    // the character base.
    SkinnedMeshRenderer r = root.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    r.sharedMesh = new Mesh();
    r.sharedMesh.CombineMeshes(combineInstances.ToArray(), false, false);
    r.bones = bones.ToArray();
    r.materials = materials.ToArray();
    r.useLightProbes = true;

    Debug.Log("Generating character took: " 
           + (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime) * 1000 + " ms");

}
```

***CurrentCharacter.cs***

```
    [PunRPC]
public void InitModel(GameObject prefab, GameObject model, int id){
    character = prefab;
    InitModel (model, id);
}

public void InitModel(GameObject model, int id)
{
    parenting (model, id);
    _photonView.RPC ("parenting", PhotonTargets.Others, model, id);
}
[RPC]
void parenting(GameObject model, int id){
    model.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Girl");
    model.transform.parent = character.transform;
    model.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    InitMouseLook (model);
    InitAnimations (model);
    if (id == PersistentData.Instance.LoggedInUser.m_id) {
        CurrentCharacter.persistentMainModel = model;
    }
}
```